# Mousewheel scroll on flash content

Tags: javascript, flash, dom-events, mousewheel

I'm trying to change event for mousewheel after leaving / entering flash content.

1. on flash - I want to scroll flash carousel
2. on web   - I want to scroll web content

My problem is:

Different browsers give different "focus" for flash element and therefore not properly triggered in events: `Event.MOUSE_LEAVE`, `MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER`. I have JS triggered for `MOUSE_OVER` and `MOUSE_LEAVE` but this seems not to work.

Also mouseWheel is attributed to the browser, not a flash object.

Firefox 4.x/5.0 - fires them properly, without clicking
Chrome 12.0.742.112 - it fires after the grant of "focus" or click on the flash object, like IE 9.0.1

JS code:

```
function stopWheel(e){
    if(!e){ e = window.event; } /* IE7, IE8, Chrome, Safari */
    if(e.preventDefault) { e.preventDefault(); } /* Chrome, Safari, Firefox */
    e.returnValue = false; /* IE7, IE8 */
}

function player_enter(){
    document.onmousewheel = function(){ stopWheel(); }  /* IE7, IE8 */
    if(document.addEventListener){                      /* Chrome, Safari, Firefox */
        document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', stopWheel, false);
    }
}

function player_leave(){
    document.onmousewheel = null;                       /* IE7, IE8 */
    if(document.addEventListener){                      /* Chrome, Safari, Firefox */
        document.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', stopWheel, false);
    }
}
```

Is there anything I could change?

Answer (score -1):

in flash you can listen for the mouse wheel event. and if you do have an event listener there, then it will stop the wheel even from propagating to the html page. and when you are outside the flash, the wheel event is doing what it should (scrolling the website)

```
 addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, handleMouseWheel);
```

Comment: this is not true; just adding a MOUSE_WHEEL event does not prevent website scrolling

Comment: if you handle the wheel then it won't let it go to the website and it will prevent scrolling.

Comment: That is only true in AS2. In AS3, it is well known that both the flash and the browser receive the scroll event. See http://code.google.com/p/mousewheeltrap/. I don't list this as a solution because I am in fact looking around for a problem using it on Chrome + Mac. In that situation, it does prevent the browser from scrolling, but Flash also does not receive the event.